# Need Suggestion in designing Redis structure

Tags: node.js, redis

We are developing system that deals with millions of records.

**Redis Structure**
Regarding Redis structure we are planning to use Hashes for each device,users etc and all searchable/querying  fields would be added as sets in the hash like below 
Below is the node.js code (Its POC code)

```
 var key ="dvc:"+data.id;
    client.hmset(key,data,function(err, item){


        client.sadd("tag:"+data.Tag,key,function(err, result1){

        })
        client.sadd("serialNo:"+data.SerialNo,key,function(err, result1){

        })
        client.sadd("currentStatus:"+data.Status,key,function(err, result1){

        })
        client.sadd("createdOn:"+data.CreatedDate,key,function(err, result1){

        })

        if(data.Boxes && data.Boxes.length > 0) {
           for loop to add all boxes 
            client.sadd("boxes:" + data.Boxes[i].id, key, function (err, result1) {

            })
        }
```

Once this is done plan is to use set queries to get all different tags , status , date , and Boxes range queries. Do you guys recommend this ? we are planning to run the load test as well .. but wanted to check if there is any better approach

**Requirement 2 we Also need Quick Search (Auto Complete )**
for this we are planning to put all searchable text in ZSET with score and use 
 zrangebylex  for searching below is sample code

```
  client.zadd("zset",1,data.Tag+"|tag",function(err, result1){
        console.log("imei "+result1);
    })

    client.zadd("zset",1,data.SerialNo+"|SerialNo",function(err, result1){
        console.log("zset "+result1);
    })
```

for get querying 
   zrangebylex zset [2073 "[2073\xff" LIMIT 0 10

Everything looks good but any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you put data in hashes and later you organize it in sets by different criterias, either in unsorted and sorted sets.

Actually, when you store data in Redis you do like if you were directly building and consuming indexes.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! what you think about redis structure.

Comment: @prakash In summary, I'm telling you in my answer that it seems fine :D